# Installing GRUB on an nvme drive

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub, nvme

I used a cloning app in windows to copy my partitions to the nvme but now I need to install a new bootloader as I am combining two drives into the one nvme.

Partition Layout:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                     Flags 
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  ntfs         Windows 10 - Reserved 1  msftdata
 2      525MB   480GB  479GB  ntfs         Windows 10               msftdata
 3      480GB   480GB  500MB  ntfs         Windows 10 - Reserved 2  msftdata
 4      480GB   481GB  537MB  fat32        EFI                      boot, esp
 5      481GB   891GB  410GB  ext4         Linux
```

So the old drive 1:
1: Win10 boot, 2: Win10 itself, 3: Win10 reserved. I would F8 at BIOS and boot this drive first to get into Windows.

The old drive 2:
4: EFI partition, 5: Linux root. This was set as my first drive to boot by default.

the EFI partition looks like this:

```
/boot/efi/:
EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
BOOT  ubuntu

/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT:
BOOTX64.EFI  fbx64.efi  mmx64.efi

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu:
BOOTX64.CSV  fw  fwupx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fw:
```

It's weird that the EFI partition has a folder named EFI as this is mounted at /boot/efi resulting in /boot/efi/EFI. If I need to combine boot to the EFI partition so the whole thing is mounted to /boot that is easy enough.

How do I set up a grub config to boot the system now?

Comment: /boot/efi/EFI/ is a standard for Ubuntu and other Linux booting from EFI, as noted in https://askubuntu.com/questions/880780/why-is-the-efi-partition-mounted